# scoped access through account /user object in emberjs init: function()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Assuming i have **emberjs model/controller/views** for **account , project and task**, and i want to scope access to the project and task through account, how do i do that in emberjs. I am looking at using **'init'** but the **'init function' is called after all the other properties are set**, so i don't know if it is still able to get a currentUser or create a default currentUser  and associate it with every ember object instance being created within the **App namespace.**

**In emberjs if i have this for instance**:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.setCurrentUser();
    //console.log(this.get("setCurrentUser")
  },

  setCurrentUser: function(json) {
    this.store.load(this.User, json);
    this.set('currentUser', this.User.find(json['id']));
  }
});
```

**Will the emberjs code above mean that whenever any part of the App namespace eg App.project is being accessed, the currentUser will first be looked, thereby ensuring the project is scoped to User**.

To make it clearer, in rails for example, i will do the scope access this way:

```
   #account-scope in Rails?
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def current_account
      @current_account ||= current_user && current_user.account
    end
  end

  #An imagined ProjectsController showing scoped access of project through account
  @projects = current_account.projects
  @project = current_account.projects.find(params[:id])
```

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Do you really need the user model in the ember app? Unless you are somehow manipulating the user object in your app I think it might be unnecessary. For example, your store could get fetch all the projects from the server, and you could leave the scoping to the server. That way all objects are scoped to the user and you don't need a superfluous user model in your app. Depends on what else your app does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Sean. Just to clarify. It is a SaaS app, so assume there should be some kind of user manipulation but to ensure I understand what you refer to as user manipulation, can you give me some examples of you what user manipulation is in your context. I was still thinking of having scoping at the server level too. When i see your response, i will see if the things you refer to as user manipulation will apply or not. thanks again.

Comment: Assuming your data model supports who owns what data and who has access to modify it, take that property and give it over to your model in Ember and you should be able to toggle the appropriate UI through binding. If you have a fiddle that you can toss up, I would be happy to look at it and offer any more tips. But, I think that overriding the constructor of an object isn't making this any easier for you. If a project has a user and a user has many projects, then you should be able to tell that pretty quickly in your bindings.

Comment: @atsjj many thanks for taking a look and offering to look at a fiddle. Here is an initial draft fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egKAH/2/

Comment: Awesome. I will look at ths today and get back to you with any questions or feedback.

Comment: This blog post does a pretty good job answering the question. Actually we don't need to use the init fuction based on the appraoch in this blog: http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js